# Allow Creating but not Overriding or Deleting Objects in a bucket in GCS and S3

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to allow Creating new objects but not deleting or overwriting other existing objects in a bucket?

I'd like to achieve this without maintaining a backend or signed URLs. If there's a way to do this through Object Default ACLs and Bucket ACL.

Setting a buckets ACL to allow `WRITING` from `allUsers` seem to allow them to delete and overwrite, I'd like them to only be able to create new objects.

Note: I'd also appreciate answers to S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not. Right now, the uploader of an object is the owner of that object, and the owner of an object always has permission to delete their own object. You could keep a set of users from overwriting each others' objects, but you can't currently prevent a user from overwriting objects that they have previously uploaded.

Note that this is strictly a question of ACLs. A user that doesn't wish to overwrite an existing object can make sure that they won't. If using the XML API, the user would including the header "x-goog-if-generation-match: 0" in their upload request, which would cause their upload to fail if an object with that name already exists.

Comment: Thanks for the response this gave me some ideas. Is it possible to upload an object (on creation) with an ACL that would prevent it from being overwritten in the future even if the user have WRITE access to the bucket it is contained in? If this is possible, it might accomplish the experience I am looking for.

Comment: Not quite. You can never prevent the same account that uploaded an object from deleting it later. The uploader is always an irrevocable owner of the object, and the owner can always delete. But if you use a signed URL when uploading, all of the objects are owned by the service account that signed the URL, and you can make it so that no other account may delete the object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can Signed URLs be obtained without maintaining a backend?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Someone holding the private key needs to sign the request. That could be a service that you operate, or it could be a service like Firebaase, but someone trusted has to do the signing.

Comment: Does Bucket Write Access also give Users permission to delete object versions?

Comment: Yes. The uploader of a specific generation of an object remains the owner of that specific generation of the object. If another user overwrites it, the new user owns the new generation, but the original uploader still owns their own generation and can still delete it.

Comment: Thanks. What does that mean if one have allUsers-WRITER on Bucket ACL? Does this mean allUsers are Owners of files and versions uploaded by other anonymous users and everything can be deleted by anyone?

Comment: It means that anyone, even anonymous people, can delete any object in the bucket, or upload any object, or overwrite any object.